# ADF What happens if <Batch count> of <Foreach Activity> is too large?

Tags: azure-data-factory

What if I have 10 "Copy Activity", And I run it in double "Foreach Activity"(batch count = `50*50=2500`).

Is it meaning that the actual Batch count is dynamic? <sup>[microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity)</sup>

> Batch count to be used for controlling the number of parallel execution (when isSequential is set to false). This is the upper concurrency limit, but the for-each activity will not always execute at this number

Answer (score 1):

What is suggested in question is a Parallel Execution.

**Parallel execution**

If `isSequential` is set to false, the activity iterates in parallel with a maximum of 50 concurrent iterations. This setting should be used with caution. If the concurrent iterations are writing to the same folder but to different files, this approach is fine. If the concurrent iterations are writing concurrently to the exact same file, this approach most likely causes an error.

As per official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#limitations-and-workarounds) there is a  limitation of the ForEach activity in terms of maximum batchCount

**Limitation –**

The ForEach activity has a maximum batchCount of 50 for parallel processing, and a maximum of 100,000 items.

**Workaround –**

Design a two-level pipeline where the outer pipeline with the ForEach activity iterates over an inner pipeline.